# cannot deploy while the apex code is currently executing

Tags: apex, deployment, eclipse

When I try to save my code in Eclipse I get this error:

> cannot deploy while the apex code is currently executing

I don't know why because I am not deploying any code. Any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: What were you doing just prior to initiating the save? Were you running any tests? What kind of code is this for? Is this a schedulable class or something like that? Please think about relevant details you can share and what kind of plug-ins you may have running in Eclipse.

Comment: i did testing the page and no test running at that moment.It just a normal code.

Comment: Even though the test had concluded, Eclipse was likely still downloading the debug logs from your org. That takes time and isn't instantaneous.

Comment: someone from other system running the batch and now its showing 'organization administration locked salesforce' and other user is trying to save the code.i will try after some time.

Comment: Gotta coordinate with your fellow developers.

Comment: Doing a save in Eclipse is a deployment in Salesforce. You start noticing that especially when your unit tests take a long time to run. Then saving in Eclipse will take a long time.